# How to see project name instead of "yii2-app-basic" in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, yii2, netbeans-8

[image: Screenshot of my Netbeans 'Projects' tab]

I want to see "jd4" as it comes on mouse hover instead of "yii2-app-basic". It gets confusing when I have multiple Yii2 apps. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: right click on this name > rename

Comment: omg thanks it was that simple. Been struggling with it for months.

Comment: You can also edit project name in nbproject/project.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: Click on it, Press f2 and rename it. Simple :)
Method 2: Right click on it, select rename and rename it. 
:)